# Python OSX $ which Python gives /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, twisted

Hello I'm trying to run **twisted** along with python but python cannot find **twisted**.

I did run **$pip install twisted** successfully but it is still not available.

*ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol*

It seems that most people have **$which python**  at **/usr/local/bin/python**

but I get **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python**

May this be the issue? If so, how can I change the PATH env?

Comment: You're probably doomed.  Re-install from OS vendor installation material and next time only install new Python package using virtualenv.

Comment: You don't have nearly enough information for a real answer here.  At a minimum, please include your OS X version (the output of `sw_vers` in Terminal) your Python version and build information (the output you get when you just type `python` in a Terminal) and a list of any Python packages you have installed with system installers (`pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i python` should approximate that).

Answer (score 17):

It is just fine.
Python may be installed in multiple places in your computer.
When you get a new Mac, the default python directory may be

```
 'usr/bin/python2.7'
```

You may also have a directory

```
'System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
```

The first one is the symlink of the second one.

If you use HomeBrew to install python, you may get a directory in

```
'usr/local/bin/python2.7'
```

You may also have a directory as

```
'Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
```

which is exactly where my directory is.

The difference between the second one and the fourth one, you may find it here
[Installing Your Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html)

In your question, as you mentioned pip install is successful, but the installed packages still not available. I may guess your pip directory is not in your default python directory, and the packages are installed where your pip directory is. (Please use `'which pip'` to check it out)

For example, in my computer, the default pip directory is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

though, I have also pip in usr/local/bin.

So, all my packages installed via 'pip install' are stored in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Hope that resolves your doubt. Similar things have happened to me, and it took me a whole night to figure out.

Here is the solution:
Use `PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"` to modify your python directory, or modify your pip directory.
However, I would recommend a better way, use **[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)**. This can isolates Python environments, and can help you easily set up packages for each project.

Answer (score 2):

By the path your giving for OS X python I'm guessing your a rev-or-so old on your OS X (leopard?) so I can't directly compare with my machine.

But, adding packages to the base OS X install is always a touchy thing, one check I would recommend is the permissions on any packages you add.  Do a `ls -l /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and make sure everything has `r` rights (and `x` rights for directories) (I.E. `-rwxr-xr-x` or `drwxr-xr-x`).

I had a recent case where a `sudo pip` wouldn't set user read rights on installed packages, and I believe "No module" was the error I was getting when I tried to use them

Because adding packages is so touchy on OS X, there are tons of guide on the net to doing hand installs of python.  The first one I matched on a google is [Installing / Updateing Python on OS X](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/) (use at your own risk, I personally haven't followed that guide)

(... the 3rd part install system [Brew](http://brew.sh) is a very common method for people to do automated installs of python as well)

Comment: actually what solved the problem for me was to add to .bash_profile PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

Okay well in the terminal I finally found out:

open .bash_profile located at your user root (simply do a `$cd` in terminal to go there) and add where the path is the location of twisted

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" 
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Watch out as you continue to install python stuff on that machine, that isn't the normal install directory for the pre-installed OS X python, so whichever install tools your using may get more and more confused with time.  If your going to keep working on there you would likely be best off setting up a virtual env on a hand install python.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting a `ImportError: No module named xxx`even though I did a `pip install xxx` and `pip2 install xxx`.
`pip2.7 install xxx` worked for me. This installed it in the python 2.7 directory.